# Save access record if any field on form is edited

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I am trying to save the record when any field on the form is edited. Is this possible? I know I could put code under each control in the after update event but I would like to know if there is a easier way that could watch if any field was changed then save the complete record.

Comment: the forms dirty property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194309.aspx

Comment: Are you saying just add a line of code Me.dirty=True to the current event of the form

Comment: or what ever you are using to navigate away, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the *OnCurrent* event to save the record. Think about it: The record you left will have been saved before that event will fire when you arrive on the other record.

Thus, you have to add code to all relevant controls' *AfterUpdate* events.

Writing all that code can be avoided using *WithEvents*. An example can be found [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html) which includes a link to an intro article by *John Colby*.